# Why should I use <tbody> <thead> <tfoot>?

Tags: html

Is there any point of using `<tbody> <thead> <tfoot>` instead of `<div>` tag when I'm writing table ? Because  I can't see any difference between it. I've tried using both of them but there's no difference visually? Any explanation would be nice.

Comment: What does `<div>` have to do with creating a table?

Comment: One good reason to use the proper tags is that they better represent the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) of what's inside them. A computer can tell `thead` is a table header, but it can't tell that a `div` is a table header!

Comment: Why use table, tr and td when you can just use divs? It's the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div is not allowed in places that thead, tbody, and tfoot are allowed.

Putting one there will force browsers to perform error recovery.

This can result in the div being entirely ignored as per this example (which attempts to place a div around the middle tr element):

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

First of all; a `<div>` [isn't allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), although many browsers are forgiven and will try to render table nonetheless.

Furthermore; the `<tbody>`, `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` tags arent mandatory, you can place `<tr>`'s as a direct child of a `<table>` element, that's all fine.

But to answer your question; why would you use them? Semantics and styling.

As for the first; html is meaningful. The content of tags, wether they be implicit or explicit translate to something we, humans, understand. It can be a paragraph, an image, a link, whatever. Besides you and me, search engines understand semantics as well; they can distinguish a header (eg. `<h1>`) from a paragraph and give more weight to the header contents when ranking a page.

The same applies to tabular data; in the `<thead>` you'll place column names, but the actual data resides in the `<tbody>` element, and will be considered as such by search engines.

A nice sideeffect is that you can use css to style the table header and footer different from the body, eg;

```
thead { font-size: 2em; } /* Big fonts for column names */
tbody { font-size: 1em; } /* Normal fonts for data */
```